# We had to do a restore from a month-old backup, now there is a conflict with order numbers. How to set Order numbers to be issued higher?

Tags: orders, magento-1.9.1.1

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

We had to do a complete restore from a month old backup. Now there is a problem with Paypal versus the Order numbers because Magento is assigning the Order numbers that we already used/assigned in the month since.

**How can I set Magento to start assigning order numbers from a higher number (to skip a thousand or so)?**

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=order_number;` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using this module: http://www.aschroder.com/category/set-start-order-number-extension/